# Netbeans not showing git changes on Windows but is on Mac

Tags: git, netbeans

I have a Java project which I work on either on my Mac or a Windows box (depending on where I am in the house).

The Windows box is not registering changes for git (so there is nothing to commit, and nothing to push to GitHub). Here's the project screenshot

[image: Project explorer view on Windows]

However, here is the exact same project on my Mac (showing all of the uncommitted changes in the last hour or so).

[image: Project Explorer View on Mac]

It might be as simple as some IDE option turned on or off. However, other projects which I edit on multiple machines are showing Git information.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Git plugin for Netbeans correctly configured on Windows?  I mean, has it ever worked?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - yes it definitely has worked in the past. It just stopped.